# File Upload Error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

I written custom module to upload bulk import of products with error report.
Here is the code I am using to move CSV file to particular location.
I am getting error always saying that

> **"Uploaded file doesn't exist.File not moved"**

My code as follows. Please correct me if I am wrong:

```
 $file = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('product_custom');  
        //print_r($file);exit;
        $file_name = $file["name"];    
        $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
          $org_target_path = $this->_dir->getPath('pub')."/uploads/".$vendorId."/original/";
         if (!is_dir($org_target_path)) { mkdir($org_target_path , 0777, true); }        

            $base_filename =  pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // get the extension of the file
            //$org_newname = $base_filename."_original.".$ext;
            $org_target = $org_target_path.$file_name;

          //  $newname="./videos/".$video_name;
            $orig = isset($_FILES['product_custom']) && isset($_FILES['product_custom']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['product_custom']['tmp_name'] : '';
            if (empty($orig)) {
              echo "Uploaded file doesn't exist.";
            }
            $copied = move_uploaded_file($orig, $org_target);
            // Optional
            if ($copied) {
              echo "File moved.";
            }
            else {
              echo "File not moved.";
            }
```

Comment: Use `echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
die;` and check what response you are getting, by doing this you can debug the value of your `$_FILE` array

Comment: Array
(
    [product_custom] => Array
        (
            [name] => Women_Sarees_a9pvOFeTHfOTgczh_1552479602.csv
            [type] => text/csv
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpmp6blc
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 4009
        )

)
 got this response

Comment: That really confusing, +1 on your question

Comment: What if you change empty to isset?

Comment: yes it worked for me , I changed to isset.